# what is mean -(IBAction) behavior function?

Tags: iphone

hi i'm studying iOS but i have a trouble.

here are four kind of functions..

```
-(IBAction) behavior : (UIButton *) sender;

-(IBAction) behavior : (id) sender;

-(IBAction) behavior : sender;

-(IBAction) behavior;
```

i know about top three things. but i don't know about the last function

```
-(IBAction) behavior;
```

what is mean? and when i use this?

if i have a button, then i can use this function

but i can't use that. if i have a slider, or picker view.. whatever

it's the only use for button??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-(IBAction) behavior:(UIButton *)sender;
```

This means that you've declared a method called `behavior:`, and you know that the thing that will be sending you the `behavior:` message is a `UIButton`.

```
-(IBAction) behavior:(id)sender;
```

This means that you've declared a method called `behavior:`, but you're not sure what kind of object will be sending you the message, so you're going with a generic "any object" (`id`).  This method is technically identical to the first one.  The only difference between them is during code compilation, and *not* at runtime.

```
-(IBAction) behavior:sender;
```

This is incorrect and shouldn't compile.

```
-(IBAction) behavior;
```

This means that you've declared a method called `behavior`, and you're ignoring the object that's sending you the message.  This is only valid with the iOS SDK (and possibly the Lion SDK, though I haven't tried it).

Answer (score 0):

Say this `-(IBAction) behavior` will only be called by one GUI component, which means you don't need to determine in `-(IBAction) behavior` what button get pressed, then you don't need a parameter there.

On the other hand, if you have two GUI component will trigger this very same function, then you want to know which one trigger it, and probably do different things, then you'll need a parameter there.

The first one means this function can be trigger by any object, second one means it's only for UIButton, I think the third one is wrong.